# A check text numbers, alphabets, letters upper case and lower case except symbols

Tags: python, python-2.7, computer-science

I need guys your help. 
I can't understand what to use either list or set. List is more efficient. dictionary also need index. but my problem is text should be string so variable must equal to text as string. I can't D=['a','b','c'].
text gives me error because it can't compare them all except individual and i must create such as abc or word example as _success and confirm its in the list to be true.

This is my code so far but i have problem which is now it accepts numbers and letters and symbols. Symbols such as !@#$% should be returning False. 
Having it as own function works but i need it in the if statement.
return text.isalnum() doesn't work in the if statement. Thats my problem symbols should be false.

```
def check(text):
    if text== '':
        return False
    if text.isalpha() == text.isdigit(): 
        return True
    else:
        return text.isalnum()





def main():           
    text = str(raw_input("Enter text: "))
    print(check(text))
main()
```

output problem.
Enter text: _
False

_ is suppose to be one of the symbols True. Example _success123 is True
!@#$% is suppose to be false but its showing as True as output Another example is !@#A123. This output is False.

The code up there does accept the underscore and letter and number 
output:
_success123 
but problem is also accepts !@#$ as True.
 return text.isalnum() Does deny the symbols but its not working in the if statement.

Comment: So, do you want to check whether the text consists only alphabets and numbers?

Comment: I wanna check letters and underscore and numbers. But if its actually symbol it should be false. So far I got working alphabets and numbers but problem is also symbols are working. text.isalpha == text.isdigit() return True. _success100 works and so symbols. symbols should be giving me False  example this is suppose to be False !@#$%

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to print. Please [edit] the question to include a handful of example inputs and show what the expected output for each is, we would then understand better what the script is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's an overkill, but you can use Regex. It's easy to add new chars (e.g. symbols):

```
import re
def check(text):
    return re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_!]*$', text)

text = str(raw_input("Enter text: "))
print(check(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a regular expression, you could use Python sets:

```
allowed = set('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_0123456789')

def check(text):
    return not len(set(text) - allowed)

for text in ['_success123', '!@#$%']:
    print(text, check(text))
```

This converts your text into a set of characters and removes all the characters that are allowed. If any characters remain then you know it is invalid. For two examples, this gives:

```
_success123 True
!@#$% False
```